# InvalidArgumentError while using tf-Faster-RCNN for object detection

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am facing the following error when using tensorflows Faster-RCNN for object detection:

```
"InvalidArgumentError : ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence  [[Node: model/rpn/target/PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32], Tout=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_0", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](model/rpn/cls/conv_1/Mul/_2579, _arg_Placeholder_2_0_2, _arg_Placeholder_1_0_1, model/rpn/target/PyFunc/input_3, model/rpn/target/PyFunc/input_4)]]
 [[Node: losses/fast_rcnn_cls_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/Shape/_2565 = _HostRecv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_5640_losses/fast_rcnn_cls_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/Shape", tensor_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]".
```

I have checked that all my images contain valid bounding boxes. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I am also encountering this problem. Have you manage to resolve it ? If so, you can write an answer and help us all ^^

Comment: No I was not able to resolve this unfortunately :/ But I figured that this error has something to do with too small/too large bounding boxes in the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** remove zero-width bounding boxes from your data and **also from [the caches](https://github.com/endernewton/tf-faster-rcnn/blob/0f23e3d726c665b95471d940b921c8d0785fd0cd/lib/datasets/pascal_voc.py#L104)**

---

I was using the [CTPN](https://github.com/cipri-tom/text-detection-ctpn/) text detector, which is based on Fast(er)-RCNN, when I was getting this error.

I noticed that some of my bounding boxes had `width=0`. So I cleaned them up, but the error was persisting. The changes were not reflected because the code was using a cache. So I removed the cache from the `data` folder and rerun the code.

Hope this helps someone.